# What are the most important writings of Rav Kook for Emunah and Hashkafah?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, jewish-books, faith-bitachon-emunah, abraham-isaac-kook, psychology

I would like to return to learn some of the writings of Rav Kook in order to improve my Hashkafah and Emunah. In the past I attended an Israeli "dati leumi" yeshiva where i learnt a bit of them, but the Hebrew, at that time, was too difficult for me.

I'm interested most specifically in his views on history and Western ideologies and on the psychology of the believer.

The problem is, now I have no access to his many books and I cannot skim through them. I can ask from someone who is travelling to Israel to buy one or two of them to me, but, before, I'd like to know what would be the best books to buy for me.

Can someone provide be with a summary of the most significant writings of Rav Kook and their content?

Comment: Most of his books can be found on hebrewbooks.org; search for "קוק" in the author field.

Comment: @ba see also http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%22%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A7

Comment: Thank you for the information, I didn't think that Rav Kook's books could be available for free

Comment: Most important in understanding his views on history is his essay "On Jewish Historiography": המהלך האידעות בישראל

Answer (score 9, accepted):

מחשבה
JEWISH THOUGHT AND PHILOSOPHY

אורות
Orot
This book presents the foundational issues in the Torah of Rav Kook:
The land of Israel, the renewal of the nation its the land and its relationship to the nations of the world.

עקבי
Ikvei Tzon
A collection of essays discussing contemporary issues. The essays include: 'HaDor-The Generation' which discusses how to relate to the questions and quandaries of the younger generation who have left the path of Torah and mitzvot. It also includes the essays: 'The Fear, Joy and Delight', 'Seeking G-d', 'Knowing G-d', 'Service of G-d', and more. Its first edition was combined with Eder HaYakar.

אורות התשובה
Orot HaTshuva 
This book deals with  intellectual and spiritual processes relating to Tshuva-Penitence. At the approach of the redemption, Rav Kook said that it was important 'to continuously learn this book'.

אורות התורה
Orot HaTorah
Rav Kook's teachings on the value of the Torah, its learning and guidance.

אורות הקדש
Orot HaKodesh
Four volumes that were collected from the Rav's manuscripts and ordered systematically. 
This was done at the request of the Rav by his student, Rabbi David Cohen, the 'Jerusalem Nazir'.

ריש
Reish Millin
This Kabbalistic book presents explanations about the inner meanings of the letters, cantillation signs and  vowel signs. It is based on the understanding that the roots of the Holy Language (Hebrew) are in the supernal worlds and that there are deep meanings and holiness connected to the forms of the letters and their pronunciations.

מאמרי
Maamerei HaRaya
A collection of essays dealing with faith, the seasons and people that the Rav eulogized. These were first published in various journals and newspapers. (2 volumes)

פרקי מחשבה
WORKS OF PHILOSOPHY AND THOUGHT
PUBLISHED AS WRITTEN WITHOUT EDITING

שמונה
Shmona Kvatzim-8 Notebooks

ארפלי
Arpelei Tohar-Cloud of Purity       Also printed as Volume 2 of the 8 Notebooks

פנקסי
Pinkasei HaRaya

קבצים
Kvatzim From His Holy Hand

פנקס 13
Pinkas 13
Also appears in 'Pinkasei HaRaya' and 'Kvatzim From His Holy Hand', Section 1

מוסר
WRITINGS ON ETHICS AND BEHAVIOR

מוסר
Musar Avicha
Guidance in matters of fear of G-d, service of G-d, fixing character traits and self evaluation.

=============================================================
מידות
Midot Ha'Raya
Explanations and discuss about various spiritual qualities including: Love, cleaving, raising the sparks, patience, reproof, etc.